# In QML, is it possible to make a row scope inside GridLayout?

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, I want to make a manipulable scope for a row of a grid.  The reason for this is I want to be able to mark a row inside of a grid as being deleted without triggering the redrawing of the entire grid, because a full redraw looks very janky and causes the GUI to pause as it re-processes all rows:

[image]

I came up with a mechanism, but it seems very hacky:

```
GridLayout {
  columns: 4;

  // header
  Text { Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter; text: 'Red';   }
  Text { Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter; text: 'Green'; }
  Text { Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter; text: 'Blue';  }
  Text { Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter; text: 'Remove?'; }

  Repeater {
    model: [
      {r: '100', g: '40', b:'27'},
      {r: '136', g: '63', b:'42'}
    ]
    Repeater {
      model: 4;
      property var pt : modelData;
      Loader {
        Component {
          id: _R;
          Text {
            text: pt.r;
            font.strikeout: !!pt.marked_for_deletion;
          }
        }
        Component {
          id: _G;
          Text {
            text: pt.g;
            font.strikeout: !!pt.marked_for_deletion;
          }
        }
        Component {
          id: _B;
          Text {
            text: pt.b;
            font.strikeout: !!pt.marked_for_deletion;
          }
        }
        Component {
          id: _Del;
          Button {
            width: text_input.font.pointSize*2;
            font.pointSize: text_input.font.pointSize*2;
            text: pt.marked_for_deletion ? '↶' :'-';
            onClicked: {
              pt.marked_for_deletion = !pt.marked_for_deletion;
              pt = pt;
            }
          }
        }
        sourceComponent: (
           index === 0 ? _R :
          (index === 1 ? _G :
          (index === 2 ? _B :
                         _Del)));

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without a strange `Loader` nested inside of a Repeater?  Can a Repeater return multiple elements without an enclosing component?  I can't use a `Column` with nested `Row` components, as the columns won't align like a table.

Comment: Seems like a valid way to go. Another might be 4 separate repeaters within the grid (probably also awkward). Another might be using a ColumnLayout (or `ListView` (no `Repeater` needed), or similar), then a RowLayout for each row, and within each column delegate set e.g. `Layout.preferredWidth: gridParent.width * 0.25` (to get even columns... could also set one column to `Layout.fillWidth: true`).

Comment: I started with the 4 repeaters, but then I can't share scope.  If I change `pt`, then the other `Repeaters` don't get the updated point.  Interesting idea on the RowLayout.  Ultimately these options still seem a little cumbersome.  Wanting to tweak one row interactively with dependencies between them doesn't seem that exotic.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: All delegates should have access to the same model data row... not sure why you would see otherwise. Perhaps because `marked_for_deletion` is a dynamic property?  Of course the model you're using doesn't have property change modifier signals, so that could be an issue as well (is that what `pt = pt` is for... to notify that the whole row was changed?). I agree it seems like a basic need (I was just doing something similar with a dynamic form layout, which needs 2 consistently sized columns for each row in the data model (a label and a form control).

Comment: Yeah, the `pt = pt` is so the row will update.  Javascript objects in Qt seem like they're copied everywhere instead of pass by reference.  Makes manipulating them in C++ a Russian doll problem.

Comment: Also, that's the reason to set the row scope. The only other way seems to be to set the entire list to itself to trigger the entire grid to re-render.

Comment: Try creating your model as an array of `QtObject`s with actual `property`ies. Or a `ListModel` (or even better, in C++ ;-) ). Eg. [Object Instances as Models](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#object-instances-as-models)

Comment: The source data is coming from a c++ wrapper around SQLite, but I'll have to investigate `QtObject`s

Comment: use Transitions to fix the jankyness of redrawing.

Comment: Is the source data implemented as a `QAbstractListModel` with the necessary change-signals? And do you want to have it *striked out* or removed? I think the problem is not a *redraw* but a *recreation of all objects*.

Comment: @derM, `modelData` seems to be a copy of the list item and not a reference.    In my example above right before `pt = pt` if I do the following: `console.log( pt === modelData );` it prints `false` in the debugger window.  It seems as though `modelData` isn't a reference, but a copy of the list item.  Would the signals still propagate across different `Repeater`s then?  If one used `QAbstractListModel` would it handle it?

Comment: I think the thing with `pt = pt` is, that it will emit a

Comment: Yeah, the `pt = pt` does seem to emit a change signal and causes the other elements in the row to update with the strikethrough which is why I did it.

Comment: Just came across yet another approach to creating columns in a `ListView` (or similar), also using one central `Component` to create each row. [How to create columns in a QML ListView](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_columns_in_a_QML_ListView).